# Windows 2003 Admin Password Lost

Tags: windows-server-2003, password-recovery

I have a windows 2003 server running a raid software.
This computer was on a domain but not anymore, i cannot login using the local account even after a password recovery through a linux live cd.
The logon screen is also forcing the user to use a domain only.

I thought about some solutions but i'm still looking for a better one :

- Create a fake domain that matches the old one and proceed.
- mount the drives on another machine
- modify registry key, local policies ...

Comment: I protected this question since anything tagged 'password-recovery' is a spam-magnet. It just does what it says in the banner, you need 10 rep to answer. Carry on.

Comment: What do you mean by the login screen is forcing the user to use a domain only? A domain with the same name wouldn't have the same SIDs, that doesn't work.

Comment: it means that when you try to enter credentials, at the logon screen, i can see username field, password field, log on (to the previsous domain to which the computer was linked to, not other choice in the dropdown)

Answer (score 2):

If you have logged into this server before try pulling out the network cable and log in using whatever password you had when you last logged into that server.  You should be able to get in with the cached credentials.

Comment: it`s an old server and nobody knows the password.

Comment: Nobody has ever logged into this server before?

Comment: it was a production server a while ago then was replaced by a new one.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Emergency Boot CD](http://www.prime-expert.com/ebcd/) or [Hiren CD](http://www.hiren.info/pages/bootcd) to blank local administrator's password.

Then, [here](http://www.nobodix.org/seb/win2003_adminpass.html) is how to change Domain Admin's password using Directory Restore Service Mode.